# Ruby array to hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
myarray = [
  ['usa','primary', 'john'],
  ['france','primary', 'lira'],
  ['usa', 'secondary', 'steve'],
  ['germany', 'primary', 'jeff'],
  ['france', 'secondary', 'ben']
]
```

I want to convert it to an array of hash like:

```
[
  {:country => 'usa', :primary => 'john', :secondary => 'steve'},
  {:country => 'france', :primary => 'lira', :secondary => 'ben'},
  {:country => 'germany', :primary => 'jeff', :secondary => ''}
]
```

I can do it by looping through the array and putting the values into a hash for "primary". How can I add "secondary" to the existing hash that may already be inserted into the array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a bit of Higher order programming:

```
myarray.reduce({}) do |accu, (country, func, name)| 
  accu[country] ||= {}
  accu[country][func.to_sym] = name
  accu 
end.map{|k, h| h[:country] = k; h}
```

#### Explanation:

Reduce will take an accumulator, in this case we start with an empty hash and go through the array. We match the triples in the array to the variables `country, func, name`. Since we want to group things by country we create that as our first Hash key. It should contain a hash so we make sure that is corresponds to an array with `accu[country] ||= {}`.

Then we add our key value pair converting `func` to a symbol. Finally we return our modified accumulator that will be passed to the next iteration.

This will return a data structure like this:

```
{"usa"=>{:primary=>"john", :secondary=>"steve"}, 
 "france"=>{:primary=>"lira", :secondary=>"ben"}, 
 "germany"=>{:primary=>"jeff"}}
```

Now we need to transform it into a array of hashes rather than a big hash. We do this by calling `map` on it and in the process we add `country` as a key to the hash.

Now one thing that the algorithm above doesn't do is to check for missing values, resp. it doesn't guarantee that both `:primary` and `:secondary` are present. You can do that by modifying the `map` to this:

```
.map do |k, h|
  h[:country] = k
  h[:primary] ||= ""
  h[:secondary] ||= ""
  h
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But here you put country name outside e.g. "usa"=>{:primary=>"john", :secondary=>"steve"} while I wish to have {:country => 'usa', :primary => 'john', :secondary => 'steve'}

Comment: Try running the code, it does exactly that. What I talk about in the answer is the intermediate step between `reduce` and `map`. Please read carefully.

Comment: you rock man :) but let me ask you, what if we have more than one identity to group by. For example, myarray = [
  ['usa', 'california', 90072, 'primary', 'john'], ['usa', 'california', 90072, 'secondary', 'paul'],
  ['france', 'brittany', 73829, primary', 'lira']  that means here if I have grouping with more than one column, not only country. Group by country, state and zipcode :)

Comment: You can use an array as a hash key, so instead of having simply `accu[country]` you could have a key made out of an array of all those values.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fun, albeit confusing, way to do it.

```
format = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = {:country => k, :primary => '', :secondary => ''} }

myarray.inject(format){ |result, (c,k,v)| result[c][k.to_sym] = v; result }.values

# => [
  {:country=>"usa", :primary=>"john", :secondary=>"steve"},
  {:country=>"france", :primary=>"lira", :secondary=>"ben"},
  {:country=>"germany", :primary=>"jeff", :secondary=>""} ]
```

Basically the `format` hash defines the way you want to generate your output. The `inject` call collects the results by country. The `values` call just grabs the actual results without the country hash keys.

Comment: +1 I was wondering whether someone would use the `Hash.new` thing.